# VPN Connection using Powershell without any prompts

Tags: powershell, azure, vpn

I am trying to connect with a VPN on my server machine using this powershell command :

**rasphone.exe -d MyVPN**

**MyVPN** is the name of network i want to connect.

It opens up a windows azure virtual network dialog which prompts for user confirmation. I am manually able to connect with VPN by clicking confirm button but I want to do this without any prompts. 
I tried -confirm parameters but it is unavailable for rasphone command. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any inputs would be appreciable !

Answer (score 2):

I understand your problem connecting to Azure vNet. Here is the workaround for the same -

```
rasphone  "YOURVPNNAME"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Network Connections')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
Sleep 3
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

You get the prompt when you call rasdial. Next you make the network connection window as the active window. You hit enter by sending  `$wshell.SendKeys('~')` here. Sleep is used so that you get ample time as the previous enter again pops up a window for confirmation where again you hit the default selection.

Hope it works for you as well.